# Relation between variation of tension and frequency of a standing wave

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, frequency, interference

What is the relation between a variation of tension and the variation of frequency of standing wave in a rope? I get this expression differentiatin the relation between $f$ and $T$

$$f=\frac{1}{2L \sqrt{\mu}} \sqrt{T} \implies \frac{df}{f}=\frac{1}{2} \frac{dT}{T} \tag{1}$$

But I have problems with this exercise from *Halliday-Krane*

> What's the percentual increase of tension necessary to increase the
>   frequency of a rope from $422.5Hz$ to $440Hz$?

Using $(1)$ I get that $\frac{df}{f}=4.1 \% \implies \frac{dT}{T}=8.3\%$

While the correct result is $8.5\%$. How can that be?

Comment: Instead of considering infinitesimal changes in tension and frequency, you want the relation $f_1/f_0 = \sqrt{T_1/T_0}$

Comment: However, the numbers *are* odd. 6.8 does not come up in any case. And 440 is 4.1% greater than 422.5.

Comment: Sorry I corrected the numbers, but still doesn't seem right completely. On solution manual the following formula is used $$\frac{T_2-T_1}{T_1}=\frac{f^2_2-f^2_1}{f^2_1}\tag{2}$$Is there any difference between $(1)$ and $(2)$? And which is the correct one to use?

Comment: (2) gives 8.46% and is the correct formula. (1) is approximately correct and would give 8.2%. (1) is useful if you're asked to increase `422.5 -> 422.6` (i.e. by a really tiny amount). (2) is equivalent to the formula I suggested. Looks like a typo in the answer sheet.

Comment: I missed the corrections. As you can see, everything works out now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T= k f^2$ and $T + \Delta T= k(f + \Delta f)^2 \Rightarrow 1 + \frac{\Delta T}{T} = (1+ \frac{\Delta f}{f})^2 = 1+ \frac {2 \Delta f}{f} + \left ( \frac{\Delta f}{f}\right )^2$

$$\frac{\Delta T}{T} = \frac {2 \Delta f}{f} + \left ( \frac{\Delta f}{f}\right )^2$$

So your methods differ by the last term

Comment: That's out of the box, +1